# Calculating distance between two geographic locations

Tags: android, location, distance, latitude-longitude

please shed some light on this situation

Right now i have two array having latitude and longitude of nearby places and also have the user location latiude and longiude now i want to calculate the distance between user location and nearby places and want to show them in listview.

I know that there is a method for calculating distance as

```
public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results);
```

Now what is the problem is how to pass these two array having nearby latitude and longitue in this method and get the array of distances.

Comment: check out this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739734/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-points-in-android-app/5739789#5739789

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for you reply but i want to calculate distance using above method.

Comment: please clarify, technically you have only given us a method signature, which is not enough information to know where the method documentation can be found. Try adding information about the containing class

Comment: Stop using distanceTo because it retourns wrong values:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664031/stop-using-distanceto-of-location-it-retourns-wrong-values

Comment: @Karamsa, but in your link it is described that it works right.

Comment: Is Google Distance Matrix API the right choice for calculating the distance between two geographic locations ??

Answer (score 212, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Look into distanceTo

> Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and
> the given location. Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

or distanceBetween

> Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and
> optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between
> them. Distance and bearing are defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

You can create a Location object from a latitude and longitude:

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(latB);
locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

or

```
private double meterDistanceBetweenPoints(float lat_a, float lng_a, float lat_b, float lng_b) {
    float pk = (float) (180.f/Math.PI);

    float a1 = lat_a / pk;
    float a2 = lng_a / pk;
    float b1 = lat_b / pk;
    float b2 = lng_b / pk;

    double t1 = Math.cos(a1) * Math.cos(a2) * Math.cos(b1) * Math.cos(b2);
    double t2 = Math.cos(a1) * Math.sin(a2) * Math.cos(b1) * Math.sin(b2);
    double t3 = Math.sin(a1) * Math.sin(b1);
    double tt = Math.acos(t1 + t2 + t3);
   
    return 6366000 * tt;
}
```

Comment: Does this give the distance between two places by road ?

Comment: no it returns Displacement (The Shortest Distance Between Two Points)

Comment: `float pk = (float) (180/3.14169);` - small misspell, this is not Pi... it should be 3.141**5**9 or `Math.PI` used (also `Math` class instead deprecated `FloatMath`). 57 upvotes and no one noticed? :D

Comment: Anyone confirm whether `locationA.distanceTo(locationB)` takes the altitude into consideration?

Comment: What's the second code block for? Why wouldn't you just use `Location. distanceBetween()`?

Comment: Secret Squirrel: locationA.distanceTo(locationB) will ignore altitude, even when set using setAltitude(<meters>). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149168/what-distance-does-distanceto-returns

Comment: @Karthi is the first block return a distance in Meters?

Comment: What is difference between calculating distance using Google Distance Matrix Api versus calculating using the above code ??

Comment: This returns in _Km_ or _Miles_?

Answer (score 18):

Try This Code. here we have two longitude and latitude values and selected_location.distanceTo(near_locations) function returns the distance between those places in meters.

```
Location selected_location = new Location("locationA");
            selected_location.setLatitude(17.372102);
            selected_location.setLongitude(78.484196);
Location near_locations = new Location("locationB");
            near_locations.setLatitude(17.375775);
            near_locations.setLongitude(78.469218);
double distance = selected_location.distanceTo(near_locations);
```

here "**distance**" is distance between locationA & locationB (in `Meters`)

Answer (score 3):

There is only one user Location, so you can iterate List of nearby places can call the `distanceTo()` function to get the distance, you can store in an array if you like.

From what I understand, `distanceBetween()` is for far away places, it's output is a  WGS84 ellipsoid.

Comment: can you please suggest which one provides the exact distance?

Answer (score 3):

```
    private static Double _MilesToKilometers = 1.609344;
    private static Double _MilesToNautical = 0.8684;


    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the distance between two points of latitude and longitude.
    /// Great Link - http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="coordinate1">First coordinate.</param>
    /// <param name="coordinate2">Second coordinate.</param>
    /// <param name="unitsOfLength">Sets the return value unit of length.</param>
    public static Double Distance(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate coordinate2, UnitsOfLength unitsOfLength)
    {

        double theta = coordinate1.getLongitude() - coordinate2.getLongitude();
        double distance = Math.sin(ToRadian(coordinate1.getLatitude())) * Math.sin(ToRadian(coordinate2.getLatitude())) +
                       Math.cos(ToRadian(coordinate1.getLatitude())) * Math.cos(ToRadian(coordinate2.getLatitude())) *
                       Math.cos(ToRadian(theta));

        distance = Math.acos(distance);
        distance = ToDegree(distance);
        distance = distance * 60 * 1.1515;

        if (unitsOfLength == UnitsOfLength.Kilometer)
            distance = distance * _MilesToKilometers;
        else if (unitsOfLength == UnitsOfLength.NauticalMiles)
            distance = distance * _MilesToNautical;

        return (distance);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

distanceTo will give you the distance in meters between the two given location ej target.distanceTo(destination).

distanceBetween give you the distance also but it will store the distance in a array of float( results[0]). the doc says If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2]

hope that this helps

i've used distanceTo to get the distance from point A to B i think that is the way to go.

Comment: And what is a bearing??

Answer (score 0):

```
public double distance(Double latitude, Double longitude, double e, double f) {
        double d2r = Math.PI / 180;

        double dlong = (longitude - f) * d2r;
        double dlat = (latitude - e) * d2r;
        double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat / 2.0), 2) + Math.cos(e * d2r)
                * Math.cos(latitude * d2r) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlong / 2.0), 2)
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double d = 6367 * c;
                return d;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to implement myself this, i ended up reading the Wikipedia page on [Great-circle distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance), because no code was readable enough for me to use as basis.

C# example

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the distance between two locations using the Great Circle Distance algorithm
    /// <see cref="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="first"></param>
    /// <param name="second"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static double DistanceBetween(GeoLocation first, GeoLocation second)
    {
        double longitudeDifferenceInRadians = Math.Abs(ToRadians(first.Longitude) - ToRadians(second.Longitude));

        double centralAngleBetweenLocationsInRadians = Math.Acos(
            Math.Sin(ToRadians(first.Latitude)) * Math.Sin(ToRadians(second.Latitude)) +
            Math.Cos(ToRadians(first.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(ToRadians(second.Latitude)) *
            Math.Cos(longitudeDifferenceInRadians));

        const double earthRadiusInMeters = 6357 * 1000;

        return earthRadiusInMeters * centralAngleBetweenLocationsInRadians;
    }

    private static double ToRadians(double degrees)
    {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.distanceTo` method.
ex:

```
private fun getDistance(locationA:Location, locationB:Location){

    val distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)
}
```