# Android latitude longitude with radius

Tags: android, sqlite, latitude-longitude

I have an app where the user marks locations such as home, office etc. The latitude and longitude data for these locations are stored in sqlite DB. I am periodically checking the users current location. I want to check if the users current location falls in to a radius of a marked location.

Example, users coordinates for home are (a,b) how to find if the current coordinates (m,n) falls under a radius of 0.5 Km of home.

Answer (score 3):

You can just measure distance between two locations using `Location.distanceTo()` or `Location.distanceBetween()` methods. If the calculated distance is less than 500m, than it falls under the required radius. Hope this helps.

Comment: we have a winner, no need for complex solutions if the SDK has these methods available.

Answer (score 1):

For distance measuring between two coordinates you can find a solution here:

[Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations/8050255#8050255)

Also you can make a database query to sort your records by distance: 
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=175951.0

Answer (score 0):

or, the old fashioned way:    radius = sqrt( (m-a)^2 + (n-b)^2 ) assuming flat earth model. Once your distance is very great, this formula no longer applies