# How to get Distance Kilometer in android?

Tags: android, distance, google-places-api

I am very new to Google maps I want calculate the distance between two places in android.

For that I get the two places lat and lag positions for that I write the following code:

```
private double getDistance(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1, double lon2) {
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double temp = 6371 * c;
    temp=temp*0.621;
    return temp;
}
```

The above code can't give the accurate distance between two places. What is the another way to find distance please give me any suggestions.

Comment: What does "not accurate" look like?  A test case might help.

Comment: the distance between hyderabad  and Chennai is giving 4729.535 but the actual distance is 629 km ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)

Answer (score 20):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13206484/, with one change

```
double distance;
Location locationA = new Location(“Point A”);
locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location locationB = new Location(“Point B”);
locationB.setLatitude(latB);
locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

// distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);   // in meters
distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;   // in km
```

Comment: Its working fine but how can i check distance is right or wrong.

Comment: hey google does this calculation. who is more reliable then that. and you are providing the source and destination right. so if someone might go wrong here, that will be you.

Answer (score 1):

Use code find distance meters to km and km to miles

```
Location locationA = new Location(“Point A”);
locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location locationB = new Location(“Point B”);
locationB.setLatitude(latB);
locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);   // in meters
distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;   // in km
distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1609.344;   // in miles
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Location.distanceTo(Location) it will give you a really distance between two different Locations.