# find Distance in kilometers in Android using google places Api

Tags: android, distance, google-places-api

I want display the two places distance in kilometers for that I write the following code:

```
hyd(17.38,78.48) eluru(16.7,81.1)
 private String getDistance(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1, double lon2) {
               double Radius = 6371;
               double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
                double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
                double a = Math.sin(dLat / 5) * Math.sin(dLat / 5)
                        + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 5)
                        * Math.sin(dLon / 5);
                double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                double km = Radius * c;

                String kms=Double.toString(km);
                return kms;

                }
```

Output = 2995.8772

Correct o/p = 330km

how can I get the the exact distance between two places in android 
thanks in advance.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of the OP's question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13208501/450534

Comment: but i didnot get the actual result can u sugesst?

Comment: Read this: [What if I don’t get a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) Don't create duplicate posts because of that. Continue interacting with _Chirag_ who has posted an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method

```
public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results);
```

example

```
 public static double CalculateDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
 float[] result=new float[1];
 Location.distanceBetween (lat1,lng1,lat2, lng2,  result);
 return (double)result[0]/1000; // in km
}
```

Comment: i am not getting the exact distance it showing wrog distance?

Comment: because google gives distance in shortest path possible and it does not follow your path to compute distance. for your ref - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])