# Find Distance between multiple points

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to get those points from database which are at some specified distance like within 2km from the given point. for this i use the following query in sqllite,

```
    public Cursor GetLoc(int lat, int longi, int dist)
    {   
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT *, ((Math.acos(Math.sin("+ lat +"* PI() / 180) * Math.sin("+ LATITUDE +"* PI() / 180) + Math.cos("+ lat +"* PI() / 180) * Math.cos("+LATITUDE+"* PI() / 180) * Math.cos(("+ longi +" - "+LONGITITUDE+") * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) AS distance FROM " + LOCATION_TABLE +" WHERE distance = " + dist, null);
        return c;
    }
```

in this query LATITUDE and LONGITITUDE are columns of LOCATION_TABLE.

this query gives correct result in mysql but here it give this error

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "("
```

i didnt get where is problem in the query. Plz help.

Comment: You will have an easier time if you pull the data out from the database, store it in memory, and then compute the calculation.  I have a feeling that asking sqllite to do the calculation is not as efficient.

Comment: Also, why are you using the trig functions for a simple distance calculation? [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) could help you out here...

Comment: @stealth-rabbi, i know that way but if 1000 locations are saved in database than it will effect program efficiency as i have to run this function whenever location will be changed. do you think its a good idea to do this type of processing when large number of locations are saved????

Comment: @Geobits: this is not as simple as to get distance only between two points.

Comment: @Geobits He's calculating distance between points on a sphere (the earth), and must account for the radius: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Radius_for_spherical_Earth

Comment: How often are the database positions updated? It seems like you'd want to keep the DB records in RAM, and recalculate your distance equation on demand (as the user views it / when your position changes).

Comment: @user1743317 As long as SQLite does not have an index for metric data--which is doesn't have--the system will perform the same procedure either in your SQL query or in the code. In other words, you will search the whole database anyway.

Comment: @StealthRabbi True, I was thrown off by the example he gave I guess(2km), since it would hardly matter at such a short distance. For larger distances, yea.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Android, I suggest using the Location class's [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) method. I wouldn't request the DB to perform this operation

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations).