# get distance between Current location and Selected Place in android

Tags: android, geolocation, android-mapview, android-location

I am new to android developing, I want to make an application like give me distance on MapView between my current location and selected place.

please give me some suggestion for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8050255/792232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get the distance between current location and a selected place using android.**

```
public static double distFrom(
    double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
{
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1); 
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * 
        Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    double dist = earthRadius * c; 

    return dist; 
}
```

Comment: or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29

Comment: @ankitmakwana Can you tell me how to put longitude and latitude point on WebView?

Comment: @PratikButani you can display Using GeoPoint

Comment: @ankitmakwana I want to display Current Location on MapView, Help for that.

Comment: simle place icon using current lat and long create Geo point  and show it

Answer (score 0):

Only a few lines of code:

```
Location l1=new Location("One");
l1.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
l1.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

Location l2=new Location("Two");
l2.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(frnd_lat));
l2.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(frnd_longi));

float distance_bw_one_and_two=l1.distanceTo(l2);
```