# Google maps api v2 how to find the nearest location

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google maps api v2 in android. I have created xml parser for the bus stop. Bus stops are displayed using markers. I need to find the user's current location and find the nearest location (bus stop), best automatically (for example in a radius of 0.5 kilometer).

I tried to find a tutorial, but unfortunately I failed it. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the distanceTo() method of Location class that gets the distance between 2 locations, in a straight line. You can find an example on how to use this here: [How to get straight distance between two location in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594924/how-to-get-straight-distance-between-two-location-in-android)

But, if you don't want the straight line distance, rather the Travel distance, I'd recommend you take a look at this question and answer: [Get the distance between two locations in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310126/get-the-distance-between-two-locations-in-android)