# How can I do to calculate my distance from a marker on google-maps-v2 on android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi guys I'm new on android. I was wondering on how can I do to calculate the distance between the device and a marker placed on the map? If possible at runtime; while I walk on the city I'll see the meters fall while I'm more near to the marker, this is the situation on my mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating distance between two geographic locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)

Comment: but this is an "aerial distance" I wanna the route distance..

Comment: Then you need to look at Google Directions API

Comment: ah .. thanks, I tought that was integrated in google maps api... @tyczj