# Do action when user crosses 2km distance from current location

Tags: java, android, methods

I want an method which gets lon and lat and should return true when user is under 2km location using the lon and lat he fixed..but i dont know how to implement it can any one give idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a feature called [Geofencing](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html). Look there on the sample app. Use this feature with caution because it can drain the battery.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you want to do but I'm guessing you want to calculate the distance between two locations(Or more), You can use distanceTo method:

```
Location a = new Location("Source");
Location b = new Location("Destination");
float distance = a.distanceTo(b); // The distance in Meters
```

See more information here - [Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)

Comment: No am asking when user croses 2km distance from current location return false