# How to calculate distance and time to location

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I need to calculate time and distance between current location to given location using gps.

any one please give idea

```
  final TextView speedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedtxt);
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationListener = new LocationListener() {
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
             if (location.hasSpeed()) {
                float speed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6f;// km/h
                speedView.setText(String.format("%.0f km/h", speed));
            }
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Location has the `distanceTo` method that returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location. E.g

```
float distance = gpsLocation.distanceTo(dstLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at  **Location.distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)** method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

```
//finding the distance between destination and mylocation

                Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude , startLongitude, endLatitude , endLongitude , results);
// to convert metre to KM
                if(results[0]>1000)
                {
                    distString = (double)Math.round(results[0]/1000)+"km";

                }
                else
                {
                    distString = Math.round(results[0])+"m";
                }
                Log.d("dist string",distString);
// Store the distances in array

                distance[i]=distString;
```

and just chek, there is already asked question

[Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)