# How to measure the shortest distance between two geological points?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

> How to measure the shortest distance between two geological points?
>   All that I got(Location.toDistance() , manually made equation) , gives the longest distance. 
>   Suppose I am trying to get the distance from dhaka to new delhi, as the earth is round, There can be two distances--one from one side, and another from the other side.
>   I am getting only the biggest one. How can I get the shortest one?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations) should help out. The Location class in Android also has a [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) and distanceTo method.