# What distance does distanceTo returns?

Tags: android, distance

Does it take into account altitude changes?

I mean, if I start in left vertex of this triangle and end in the right upper vertex, does it return distance a or b?

```
double distanceInMetersFloat = initialPosition.distanceTo(finalPosition);
```

In my app, both initialPosition and finalPosition are Location with altitudes (I set them with Google Elevation API).

According to Google:

> Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

But you can do it with or without altitudes.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to test this yourself by trying a fixed `initialPosition` and two `finalPosition` values that differ only in altitude. If the API does not take altitude into account, it's easy enough to adjust the result in your own code for altitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The altitude is not taken into account when computing `Location.distanceTo`.

You can test it like this:

```
Location location1 = new Location("");
location1.setLatitude(40);
location1.setLongitude(-4);
location1.setAltitude(0);

Location location2 = new Location("");
location2.setLatitude(30);
location2.setLongitude(-3);
location2.setAltitude(0);

Location location3 = new Location("");
location3.setLatitude(30);
location3.setLongitude(-3);
location3.setAltitude(100);

Log.e("Without altitude", ""+location1.distanceTo(location2));
Log.e("With altitude", ""+location1.distanceTo(location3));
Log.e("Different altitude", ""+location2.distanceTo(location3));
```

This is the output:

> `E/Without altitude﹕ 1113141.5`
>
> `E/With altitude﹕ 1113141.5`
>
> `E/Different altitude﹕ 0.0`

Comment: So I was calculating tan instead of sin. Thank you.

Comment: Take into account that trigonometric approximations are only valid on short distances