# Movement tracker with GPS using LocationListener

Tags: java, android, gps, locationlistener

I am trying to make an app that tracks user movement.
so far i have an app that shows the location and the "speed"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationListener.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,10,locationListener);

}
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
String longitude = "Long: "+ loc.getLongitude();
String latitude = "Lat: "+ loc.getLatitude();
txt.setText(longitude + latitude);
}
```

this is my code.
but i want to get my speed, trip distance and max and min altitude.
if ANYONE can help, please do, it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);` is that `;` a typo?

Comment: no actually not :D

Answer (score 1):

You can find here how to calculate distance between two locations: [Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations) . I would calculate distance between every location in `onLocationChanged` and add those distances to have tripDistance.

When You have distance it is easy to calculate speed by dividing distance by time:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //(in onCreate()
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //(in onLocationChanged())
long deltaTimeInSeconds = (currentTime - startTime) * 1000;
double speed = tripDistance / deltaTimeInSeconds;
```

To have altitude you can use `loc.getAltitude();`. You can have two variables: `double minAltitude, maxAltitude;` and in every `onLocationChanged()` update them accordingly.