# Current location is with in a specific radius Android

Tags: android

I need to check if the gps location(lat,long) are with in the 50 meter radius of a specific defined lat long through my android application.

Comment: Thats very nice for you. But what is the question? Please see the guide in the help center on how to ask questions on StackOverflow

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating distance between two geographic locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)

Answer (score 1):

**Geofence is what you are looking for**

Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest.

Try out :

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html