# How to track route of user between two locations?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-location, google-distancematrix-api, google-directions-api

I have two Addresses let say Location A and Location B. And I have series of location between those Location A and Location B. I get those series of locations via Fused location API. and saved them on the server. Now following are my requirements :

**What I want:** 
                I want to calculate the distance between the Location A and Location B. Right Now I am using a code (link of post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)) but it is giving me displacement.

**Problems and Confusions:**

- I know about Google Distance matrix API and Google Directions api, but I really do not want to work on these apis as these are costly to me. But if I use them, I really did not understand that how API will know the route user selected. I mean it is possible that User has adopted the long way towards his destination. And I think google Direction and Distance API are returning the distance between Location A and Loation B using shortest route.

> I really do not want to use the API, but if there is non other
>   possible way to do that then How could I get that ? and what is best
>   for me. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: What has the distance between A and B to do with the way the user moved from A to B?

Comment: i didnt understood what are you asking ?

Comment: A and B are at a distance of three km. The user travels from A to B and walks six km. What does the distance of A to B have to do with how much a user walks?

Comment: mmmm let me explain, let say there are Location A and B . and there are possible routes to them let suppose , route x = 5 km , route y = 8 km and route z  12 km, 

now user is going on route y. and I am getting his location at regular intervals until he arrives at location B. now I should get his distance as * km 

but when I did it with Distance and Direction API , it always returns me 5 Km distance. as it is shortest.

Comment: I want to get the real distance of the route user drove or walked on. 
so as you said how much user walked (we can say it)

Comment: Well then edit your post as distance of A to B has nothing to do with the length of a track.

Comment: what should I call it then ?

Comment: I already told you in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just idea of your logic but you do not know what it is called. Though it is too late but I am posting for your information or in case of if someone later on visit here.

To draw lines between two points on Map,Use Polylines and polygons. To read further I will refer you to this google page, It has a breif introduction and also a source code. And it is even really easy to implement. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial) you go.

Comment: yes this is what I did. Accepting your answer since it is correct way to do it.