# Is it possible to parse a LatLng object type to a Location?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm looking to use Android's `distanceTo()` method to calculate the distance between the two different object types. I'm using a `LatLng` `object` as it can be added to a `marker` position on Google Maps.

```
 LatLng clontarfFC = new LatLng(53.369615, -6.1859571);
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(clontarfFC).title("Clontarf FC").snippet("St.Annes Park, Clontarf"));
```

When I add a Location object type into .position() it results in an error as they are incompatible.

I'm declaring a location `object` like so that will represent the current location of the user of the app.

```
    Location currentLocation = new Location ("Curent Location");
    currentLocation.setLatitude(53.3419322);
    currentLocation.setLongitude(-6.2670159);
```

And I'm attempting to find the distance between the two like so:

```
    final float distance = clontarfFC.distanceTo(currentLocation)/1000;
    final String formattedDistance = String.format("%.02f", distance);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050255/3505534

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not a duplicate question. That answer covers the distanceTo() method between 2 Location objects as opposed to what I'm trying to measure which is 1 LatLng object and 1 Location object

Comment: Try your code by making Longitude value as positive once.

Comment: If I take out the negative and make the longitude positive the marker moves 500 miles away from where it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know there is no built-in method for this, you could however create a simple but thorough converter, like this (where latLng is your LatLng object):

```
  Location location = new Location("location_name");
  location.setLatitude(latLng .latitude);
  location.setLongitude(latLng .longitude);
  location.setTime(new Date().getTime());
```

To convert back to LatLng use the following:

```
  LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), 
  location.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency in your gradle file and

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```

implement below line of code and pass "start LatLng" and "End LatLng" to get the distance between two objects

```
double distanceBetween = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(
                    beginLatLng, endLatLng);
```

Answer (score 0):

as said fuzzKity you can do `LatLng position = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());`

and you can do something like that

```
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(coordStart.latitude, coordStart.longitude, position.latitude, position.longitude, results);
double dist = results[0];
```