# Mark geo location on android app whose locations are exist within 5Km radius values around me.

Tags: java, android, dictionary, geo

I have list of latitude and longititude value list in orcle database table.
In Android app i want to mark those locations which take radius value bellow 5Km around my current geo location.How can I do it?
Any one who can solve the proble please give me sample android code.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations) may help

Answer (score 0):

I use firebase db with geoFire to resolve this issue. If you can get every point from your db you can check "distance" like:

```
double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(pointCoordinate, myCoordinate);
```

from `import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;`.
 But it can be problem if you have big db with lot of points.

Comment: Also look at this article https://technology.amis.nl/2017/05/17/oracle-database-standard-geo-location-support-using-locator-included-in-every-edition/

Answer (score 0):

```
 double distanceInMiles = Utils.calculateDistanceBetweenGeoPoints(
                                    currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                                    currentLocation.getLongitude(),
                                    otherLatitude,
                                    otherLongitude);
```