# Android Distance between location, What the result mean

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I have a function that return the distance between 2 locations

This is my function

```
  public static float GetDistance(Location locationA,  Location locationB ){
        float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
        return  distance;
    }
```

The float result what does it mean? air distance in kilometers?

I get 1.1 or 1.9 what does this result mean

Thanks

Comment: [Look this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location) Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can help you :
[Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)

> Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location. Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.